# How to make a ribbon on top of a div with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a ribbon like this images :
[image]

Teach me how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want : http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/

You have the html code and css on the bottom. Search a little next time.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to `rotate` the div and use `absolute` position to move it around. In the example you gave, you would want to move it to the top and left.

I have done a basic layout for this, please do feel free to edit the values and CSS and test this out.

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;}

#container {background-color:red;padding:2px;height:600px;}

#ribbon {
  background-color:green;
  padding:2px;
  width:100px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left: -25px;
  
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  <div id="ribbon">
  Special Offer
  </div>
  
</div>
```